# For loop index type when checking for >=0 termination condition

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, size-t

I need to loop backwards through a string.

```
// std::string str assumed to be defined at this point
for (std::size_t i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // perform some check on str[i]
}
```

**Problem description**
Now, if I use an `int i` loop index this works because i will eventually become -1 and the loop terminates. When using `std::size_t i` (unsigned) for the running index, it will become something really large when going "below" zero, so the loop doesn't terminate and will result in a segmentation fault eventually. What is the preferred way to solve this issue given that I want to use std::size_t as the loop index type since std::string::length returns a std::size_t, not an int.

**Possible solution**

```
for (std::size_t i = str.length(); i > 0; i--) {
  // perform some check on str[i - 1]
}
```

I think this is really ugly since we use i as an "offsetted" idx which is non intuitive. What would be clean solutions to this?

Comment: Do you need to know the index? Otherwise you could just use the reverse iterator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsigned int reverse iteration with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458204/unsigned-int-reverse-iteration-with-for-loops)

Comment: `std::size_t` is an unsigned number. Unsigned numbers are **always** `>=0`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OP is aware they literally state that in the question.

Comment: @Borgleader OP stated "_it will become something really large when going "below" zero, so the loop doesn't terminate and will result in a segmentation fault eventually._" Which doesn't make it clear, that he understands that such condition (`>=0`) will always be true, due to the nature of `unsigned`. He just written the observations of what happens when you do it. I argued, that no test needed to be done, in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `i` inside the loop, you can use a reverse iterator:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello, World!";
    for (std::string::reverse_iterator i = s.rbegin(); i != s.rend(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i;
}
```

Comment: Is this solution also applicable if I'd start my backwards iteration not from the very and (s.rbegin()) but from some position (given by an index) inside the string? Otherwise very nice, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can for instance do `std::string::reverse_iterator i = s.rbegin()+5` to make it not start at the end, but `5` chars before that.

Answer (score 0):

A preferable loop with an index will look like

```
for ( std::size_t i = str.length(); i != 0; i--) {
  // perform some check on str[i-1]
  //                       ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Or

```
for ( std::size_t i = str.length(); i-- != 0; ) {
  // perform some check on str[i]
  //                       ^^^^^^
}
```

Also instead of the declaration

```
std::size_t i = str.length();
```

you may just write

```
auto i = str.length();
```

Comment: @Matt Ignore the down-voting. I showed correct loops.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, but in my defense your original answer only had the first loop which was present by op (!= and > are functionally equivalent afaict in this case) and was considered ugly, so the original version of this answer was not an answer because OP was looking for something else.

Comment: @Borgleader You are mistaken. It seems you did not understand the question. The first loop shown by me is not equivalent to the loop in the question.

Comment: How is the first loop different to `for (std::size_t i = str.length(); i > 0; i--) {` (> vs != aside ofc)

Comment: @Borgleader For starters you showed a different loop than in the question. Secondly I showed how to access an element of the string using the index within the loop.

Comment: I dont its right under Possible Solution I pasted it from there